# How to get another column value while using group by clause?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I don't know how should I put this on query.
I need to have the count of employees who are under an employee with IdApprover, but this is on one table only. I want to have the name of the approver wherein corresponds to IdApprover = IdEmployee

```
SELECT COUNT(IdApprover), IdApprover, EmployeeName
FROM tblEmployee 
GROUP BY IdApprover
ORDER BY COUNT(IdApprover) DESC
```

All of columns mentioned above are on the same table.
I want to get

```
Count(IdApprover) IdApprover EmployeeName
3                 45         John Doe
2                 26         James Bond
```

Wherein employee name is the name of the approver which is also an employee.

Comment: Post a data sample and desired output (both as text)

Comment: In your query you neither group by or aggregate `EmployeeName` which will give an error.

Comment: You really need to give us enough information so we can help you. How does the schema of your employee table looks like ? Show us the data that is used to get to your expected outcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a stab in the dark I assume your tblEmployee table looks something a bit like this

```
DECLARE @tblEmployee TABLE
(
    IdApprover int not null,
    IdEmployee int not null,
    EmployeeName nvarchar(50) not null
)
INSERT INTO @tblEmployee VALUES (1,1,'Approver 1');
INSERT INTO @tblEmployee VALUES (2,2,'Approver 2');
INSERT INTO @tblEmployee VALUES (3,3,'Approver 3');
INSERT INTO @tblEmployee VALUES (1,4,'Employee 1');
INSERT INTO @tblEmployee VALUES (1,5,'Employee 2');
INSERT INTO @tblEmployee VALUES (1,6,'Employee 3');
INSERT INTO @tblEmployee VALUES (2,4,'Employee 4');
INSERT INTO @tblEmployee VALUES (2,4,'Employee 5');
INSERT INTO @tblEmployee VALUES (3,4,'Employee 6');
INSERT INTO @tblEmployee VALUES (3,4,'Employee 7');
INSERT INTO @tblEmployee VALUES (3,4,'Employee 8');
INSERT INTO @tblEmployee VALUES (3,4,'Employee 9');
```

This is what the records look like, where the first 3 records are the Approvers designated by IdApprover = IdEmployee, and the employees are linked to different employees (their approvers).

| IdApprover | IdEmployee | EmployeeName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Approver 1 |
| 2 | 2 | Approver 2 |
| 3 | 3 | Approver 3 |
| 1 | 4 | Employee 1 |
| 1 | 5 | Employee 2 |
| 1 | 6 | Employee 3 |
| 2 | 4 | Employee 4 |
| 2 | 4 | Employee 5 |
| 3 | 4 | Employee 6 |
| 3 | 4 | Employee 7 |
| 3 | 4 | Employee 8 |
| 3 | 4 | Employee 9 |

To solve your question I would use a couple of sub queries, first to get the count of Employees for each Approver (excluding the approvers themselves), and second to get the name of the Approver using your requirement of IdApprover = IdEmployee.

```
SELECT
 c.IdApprover
,a.EmployeeName AS ApproverName
,c.EmployeeCount
FROM
(
-- Get Counts first and put in sub query wrapper
SELECT
 IdApprover
,COUNT(IdApprover) AS EmployeeCount
FROM @tblEmployee
WHERE IdApprover <> IdEmployee
GROUP BY
IdApprover
) c

JOIN
(
-- Sub query to get Approver names
SELECT
 IdApprover
,EmployeeName
FROM @tblEmployee
WHERE IdApprover=IdEmployee
) a ON a.IdApprover=c.IdApprover
```

Which gives us a result of

| IdApprover | ApproverName | EmployeeCount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Approver 1 | 3 |
| 2 | Approver 2 | 2 |
| 3 | Approver 3 | 4 |